# function call via class pointer in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include"iostream"
using namespace std;
class base{

public:
 void f()
        {
        cout<<"base f:"<<endl; // prints base f:
        }
};


int main()
{
base *b; // even same out put with " base *b =NULL; "

b->f();
return 0;
}
```

O/p :  base f:

can any one please explain how the function is getting called without assigning the object to the pointer .

```
Thanks.
```

Answer (score 3):

Call of member-function with not initialized (or initialized to 0) pointer to object is undefined behaviour, however it may works since there is no attempts to access variables of object and there is no vtable here. You can look at this function like

```
void f_base(base* p)
{
   cout << "base f:" << endl;
}
```

there is no access - there is no error, on all modern-compilers it will work, but it can be changed anytime.

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid code, but since nothing in base::f() accesses a member variable, no invalid memory is getting touched.

If you add a member and try to print it out in the function, you will almost undoubtedly get a crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `new`

i.e.

```
base *b; // even same out put with " base *b =NULL; "
```

should be

```
base *b = new base;
```

... Need a `delete` to prevent memory leaks